# Find the volume of the solid $Q$ cut from the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 4$ by the cylinder $r = 2 \sin θ$ .

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I set up the integral as $$\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\sin\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} r dzdrd\theta$$ and got $\frac{16\pi}3$, but the answer is $\frac{16(3\pi-4)}9  \approx 9.64$, which is also what my calculator got too. What am I doing wrong?

$$\begin{split}
\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\sin\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} r dzdrd\theta &= 
 \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\sin\theta} r(2\sqrt{4-r^2})drd\theta \\
&= -\frac23\int_0^{\pi} (8\cos^3\theta - 8)d\theta \\
&= \frac{16}3\int_0^\pi (1-\cos^3{\theta})d\theta \\
&= \frac{16\pi}3
\end{split}$$

Comment: oops i wrote it wrong I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in a reply above, the OP's mistake was not accounting for $\cos^3\theta$ being negative in the domain ${\pi\over2}$ to $\pi$. @JoséCarlosSantos was correct in splitting the bounds, changing
$\frac{16}3\int_0^{\pi}1-\left(\cos^2\theta\right)^{3/2}\mathrm d\theta$ to $\frac{32}3\int_0^{\pi\over2}(1-\cos^3{\theta})\mathrm d\theta$, but gave a slightly incorrect final answer.

I will provide the work for solving this integral, in case anyone is interested:
$$\frac{32}3\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\cos^3\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$$
Using using a handy [cube identity](https://www.cuemath.com/trigonometry/cos-3x/), this can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}\frac{32}3\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left[1-\left(\frac14\cos3\theta+\frac34\cos\theta\right)\right]\mathrm d\theta&=\frac{32}3\left[\left(\left.\theta-\frac34\sin\theta-\frac1{12}\sin3\theta\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi/2}\right]
\\&=\frac{32}3\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac34+\frac1{12}\right]
\\&=\frac{32\pi}6-\frac{64}9
\\&=\frac{16(3\pi-4)}9.\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

You have no justification to write that$$\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\sin\theta} r(2\sqrt{4-r^2})\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta = -\frac23\int_0^{\pi} 8\cos^3\theta - 8\,\mathrm d\theta.$$In fact,\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\sin\theta} r(2\sqrt{4-r^2})\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta&=\int_0^\pi\frac{16}3-\frac23\left(4-4\sin^2\theta\right)^{3/2}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\frac{16}3\int_0^\pi1-\left(\cos^2\theta\right)^{3/2}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\frac{32}3\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\cos^3\theta\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\frac{16\pi}3-\frac{32}9.\end{align}

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to mention that OP's step to convert $\left(\cos^2\theta\right)^{3/2}$ to $\cos^3\theta$ is error-prone, when $\cos\theta$ can be negative.

Comment: Sorry I skipped a bunch of steps, but I did simplify the integral to $\frac{16}3\int_0^{\pi}1-cos^3{\theta}d\theta$

But why is the leading fraction for step 3 $\frac{32}3$ and why is the domain of the integral from 0 to $\frac{\pi}2$, but not 0 to $\pi$?

Comment: Note that it is not true in general that $\left(x^2\right)^{3/2}=x^3$; this only occurs when $x\geqslant0$. So, $\left(\cos^2(\theta)\right)^{3/2}=\cos^3(\theta)$ on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, but not on $\left[\frac\pi2,\pi\right]$. That's why what I did was$$\int_0^\pi1-\left(\cos^2(\theta)\right)^{3/2}\,\mathrm d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\left(\cos^2(\theta)\right)^{3/2}\,\mathrm d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\cos^3(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta.$$